# Gomock same method twice with different input

Tags: unit-testing, go, mocking, gomock

Note: Not a duplicate of [Mock interface method twice with different input and output using testify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62165773/mock-interface-method-twice-with-different-input-and-output-using-testify) - Different library.

I am using the `github.com/golang/mock/gomock` library to mock an HTTP client interface in order to test the behaviour of my code. My code uses the same `Post()` method on the client twice, but for 2 different endpoints.

I tried:

```golang
mockUc.EXPECT().
    Post("m-elasticsearch/_sql/translate", gomock.Eq(expectedQuery), gomock.Any(), gomock.Any()).
    SetArg(2, esQuery).
    Return(http.StatusOK, nil).
    Times(1)
mockUc.EXPECT().
    Post("m-elasticsearch/app-*/_search", gomock.Eq(esQuery), gomock.Any(), gomock.Any()).
    SetArg(2, logResults).
    Return(http.StatusOK, nil).
    Times(1)
```

But this gave me the error, telling me that the second `EXPECT()` was being considered on the first call:

```
 expected call at [...] doesn't match the argument at index 0.
        Got: m-elasticsearch/_sql/translate (string)
        Want: is equal to m-elasticsearch/app-*/_search (string)
```

I then tried using `gomock.InOrder()` like this:

```golang
first := mockUc.EXPECT().
    Post("m-elasticsearch/_sql/translate", gomock.Eq(expectedQuery), gomock.Any(), gomock.Any()).
    SetArg(2, esQuery).
    Return(http.StatusOK, nil).
    Times(1)
second := mockUc.EXPECT().
    Post("m-elasticsearch/app-*/_search", gomock.Eq(esQuery), gomock.Any(), gomock.Any()).
    SetArg(2, logResults).
    Return(http.StatusOK, nil).
    Times(1)

gomock.InOrder(first, second)
```

But this didn't help either.

Is what I'm trying to do possible here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of writing two EXPECTs, you can use DoAndReturn method and return the value as you want in one EXPECT. I could not write types because I do not know method signature.

```
    mockUc.
        EXPECT().
        Post(gomock.Any(), gomock.Any(), gomock.Any(), gomock.Any()).
        DoAndReturn(func(url, query string, ...) (int, error) {
            if url == "m-elasticsearch/_sql/translate" {
                return http.StatusOK, nil
            } else {
                return http.StatusOK, nil
            }
        })
```