# How to use gomock (or similar) to mock/verify calls to the DB?

Tags: unit-testing, go, mocking, go-gorm, gomock

Go here, using [gorm](http://gorm.io/index.html) to or/map to the DB (PSQL).

I have the following code:

```
package dbstuff

import (
    "errors"

  "github.com/google/uuid"
  "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/postgres"
)

type OrderPersister struct {
        db *gorm.DB
}

func (p *OrderPersister) GetOrder(id uuid.UUID) (*Order, error) {
        ret := &Order{}

        err := p.db.Table("orders").Where("order_id = ?", id).Scan(ret).Error
        return ret, err
}
```

I am trying to write a unit test for it like so:

```
package dbstuff

import (
    "testing"
  "errors"

  "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
)

func TestErrInternalServerError(t *testing.T) {

  // given
  id := uuid.New()
  op := OrderPersister{}

  // when
  order, err := op.GetOrder(id)

  // then
  assert.NotNil(t, order)
  assert.NotNil(t, err)

}
```

When I run this I get invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference errors because I'm not instantiating a setting a `*gorm.DB` on my `OrderPersister` instance. Is there an easy way to mock/stub this out so that my test will confirm we attempted to query the `orders` table and return the or/mapped results?

Comment: Might be worth a gander: https://github.com/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock

Comment: *"Is there an easy way to mock/stub this out ..."* As far as mocking is concerned the answer is: No, it's not possible to mock concrete types. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47643192/how-to-mock-functions-in-golang/47643967#47643967

Comment: you can wrap the db type in your own custom type that implements an interface, the interface can have all the methods of db type that you use, the wrapper of your DB type could be a member of your OrderPersister, you can them mock this new wrapper and test this code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will use [testify](https://github.com/stretchr/testify) package to writing unit tests for your code. Instead of using concrete type `*gorm.DB`, declaring DB interface for `OrderPersister` struct. Due to we CAN'T mock concrete type and its methods in Go. We need to create a abstract layer - the `interface`.

`63622995/db/db.go`:

```golang
package db

type OrmDBWithError struct {
    OrmDB
    Error error
}

type OrmDB interface {
    Table(name string) OrmDB
    Where(query interface{}, args ...interface{}) OrmDB
    Scan(dest interface{}) *OrmDBWithError
}
```

`63622995/main.go`:

```golang
package main

import (
    "github.com/google/uuid"
    _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/postgres"
    "github.com/mrdulin/golang/src/stackoverflow/63622995/db"
)

type Order struct {
    order_id string
}

type OrderPersister struct {
    DB db.OrmDB
    //DB *gorm.DB
}

func (p *OrderPersister) GetOrder(id uuid.UUID) (*Order, error) {
    ret := &Order{}

    err := p.DB.Table("orders").Where("order_id = ?", id).Scan(ret).Error
    return ret, err
}
```

Created mock object for db which implements the `OrmDB` interface. Then, you can create and pass this mock DB object to `OrderPersister` struct.

`63622995/mocks/db.go`:

```golang
package mocks

import (
    "github.com/mrdulin/golang/src/stackoverflow/63622995/db"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/mock"
)

type MockedOrmDB struct {
    mock.Mock
}

func (s *MockedOrmDB) Table(name string) db.OrmDB {
    args := s.Called(name)
    return args.Get(0).(db.OrmDB)
}

func (s *MockedOrmDB) Where(query interface{}, args ...interface{}) db.OrmDB {
    arguments := s.Called(query, args)
    return arguments.Get(0).(db.OrmDB)
}

func (s *MockedOrmDB) Scan(dest interface{}) *db.OrmDBWithError {
    args := s.Called(dest)
    return args.Get(0).(*db.OrmDBWithError)
}
```

`63622995/main_test.go`:

```golang
package main

import (
    "testing"

    "github.com/google/uuid"
    "github.com/mrdulin/golang/src/stackoverflow/63622995/db"
    "github.com/mrdulin/golang/src/stackoverflow/63622995/mocks"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/mock"
)

func TestOrderPersister_GetOrder(t *testing.T) {
    assert := assert.New(t)
    t.Run("should get order", func(t *testing.T) {
        testDb := new(mocks.MockedOrmDB)
        id := uuid.New()
        testDb.
            On("Table", "orders").
            Return(testDb).
            On("Where", "order_id = ?", mock.Anything).
            Return(testDb).
            On("Scan", mock.Anything).Run(func(args mock.Arguments) {
            ret := args.Get(0).(*Order)
            ret.order_id = "123"
        }).
            Return(&db.OrmDBWithError{Error: nil})
        op := OrderPersister{DB: testDb}
        got, err := op.GetOrder(id)
        testDb.AssertExpectations(t)
        assert.Nil(err)
        assert.Equal(Order{order_id: "123"}, *got)
    })

    t.Run("should return error", func(t *testing.T) {
        testDb := new(mocks.MockedOrmDB)
        id := uuid.New()
        testDb.
            On("Table", "orders").
            Return(testDb).
            On("Where", "order_id = ?", mock.Anything).
            Return(testDb).
            On("Scan", mock.Anything).
            Return(&db.OrmDBWithError{Error: errors.New("network")})
        op := OrderPersister{DB: testDb}
        got, err := op.GetOrder(id)
        testDb.AssertExpectations(t)
        assert.Equal(Order{}, *got)
        assert.Equal(err.Error(), "network")
    })
}
```

unit test results:

```sh
=== RUN   TestOrderPersister_GetOrder
=== RUN   TestOrderPersister_GetOrder/should_get_order
    TestOrderPersister_GetOrder/should_get_order: main_test.go:32: PASS:    Table(string)
    TestOrderPersister_GetOrder/should_get_order: main_test.go:32: PASS:    Where(string,string)
    TestOrderPersister_GetOrder/should_get_order: main_test.go:32: PASS:    Scan(string)
=== RUN   TestOrderPersister_GetOrder/should_return_error
    TestOrderPersister_GetOrder/should_return_error: main_test.go:49: PASS: Table(string)
    TestOrderPersister_GetOrder/should_return_error: main_test.go:49: PASS: Where(string,string)
    TestOrderPersister_GetOrder/should_return_error: main_test.go:49: PASS: Scan(string)
--- PASS: TestOrderPersister_GetOrder (0.00s)
    --- PASS: TestOrderPersister_GetOrder/should_get_order (0.00s)
    --- PASS: TestOrderPersister_GetOrder/should_return_error (0.00s)
PASS

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Coverage report:

[image]